# How to query a CRM 2011 Filtered View from a site on our DMZ?

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011, dmz

We have a public facing website that is querying our CRM 2011 database using the Filtered Views to display some information to our customers. We accomplished this by Impersonating a CRM/domain user we created for this purpose. We are moving the website from a server on our domain to a server in our DMZ that is not on our domain.

The problem is that now we cannot authenticate the CRM user from the server on the DMZ.

Is there some way around this?

Comment: Do you make direct SQL queries or are you calling the CRM web service? Can the server in the DMZ reach the same server (SQL or CRM) that you currently connect to?

Comment: It is making direct SQL queries. It does have access to the SQL server on port 1433.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of impersonating the domain user on the web server, you are better of using "Execute As" within the context of a stored procedure on the SQL database.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx